# Output descendants of current structure

Tags: structure, entry

I hope I worded the title correctly. I'm trying to output whatever structure's page I'm on - I want the descendants of whatever page that is. I'm currently using this, which at first appeared to work, but then my css styling doesn't get applied to any of the other entries.  See below:

```
<div class="large-4 columns">
  {% set messages = entry.getChildren() %}
     {% if messages | length %}
       <ul>
        {% for entry in messages %}
          {% for image in entry.seriesArtwork %}
            <img src="{{image.getURL('seriesThumbnail')}}">
          {% endfor %}
 </div>
    <div class="large-8 columns">
      <div id="message-title">{{ entry.title }}</div>
        <div id="message-speaker"> {{ entry.postDate|date('M j, Y')}} • {{ entry.speaker }}</div>
        </div>

    <hr>
      {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

[image: Example Image]

Answer (score 1):

This was an ordering mistake. I didn't setup my grid properly for the loop that has to take place.